# Can i legally drive in the US with a photocopy of my Indian Driving License and an IDP?

Tags: usa, driving-licenses, california

I will be travelling to the US for a vacation. I would like to rent a car for driving there but I have recently lost the original card license that I own. I have a scanned copy of my licence though. Will I be able to drive in the US legally with a photocopy of my licence and an IDP ?
Will the police in California accept it ?

Comment: Not likely.  Better to get a temporary license or replacement as the car rental company will want to see proper paperwork.

Comment: What I know, the IDP is used only to help the translation. I believe you will continue to need your original drive license.

Answer (score 4):

**No and no.** :(

But your first problem is you will be unable to rent a car without a valid Driver License.  There is practically 0% change a reputable agency will accept a photo copy of anything.